# FileInputStream is getting closed when passing second time to a function in java

Tags: java, fileinputstream

```
 public static void main(String[] args){
        try{
            FileInputStream fileInputStream=new FileInputStream("sourcefile.txt");
            File file1=new File("copy1.txt");
            File file2=new File("copy2.txt");
            //firstcopy
            FileOutputStream fileOutputStream1=new FileOutputStream(file1);
            fileCopy(fileInputStream, fileOutputStream1);
            fileOutputStream1.close();
            //secondcopy
            FileOutputStream fileOutputStream2=new FileOutputStream(file2);
            fileCopy(fileInputStream, fileOutputStream2); 
            fileOutputStream2.close();

        }catch(FileNotFoundException fileNotFoundException){
            System.err.println(fileNotFoundException.getMessage());
            fileNotFoundException.printStackTrace();
        }catch(IOException ioException){
            ioException.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    //file copy function
    public static void fileCopy(FileInputStream fileInputStream,FileOutputStream fileOutputStream) throws IOException{
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

        int length;
        //copy the file content in bytes 
        while ((length = fileInputStream.read(buffer)) > 0){

            fileOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, length);

        }

        fileInputStream.close();
        fileOutputStream.close();

        System.out.println("File is copied successful!");
    }
```

```
Output:
    File is copied successful!
    java.io.IOException: Stream Closed
        at java.io.FileInputStream.readBytes(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.read(FileInputStream.java:243)
        at FileCopier.fileCopy(FileCopier.java:38)
        at FileCopier.main(FileCopier.java:21)
```

Why my secondcopy is not working?
It is working when I am passing `"new FileInputStream("sourcefile.txt")"` directly instead of `fileInputsteam` object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because your `fileCopy()` method explicitly closes it.

You pass `fileInputStream` to `fileCopy()`:

```
fileCopy(fileInputStream, fileOutputStream1);
```

And inside `fileCopy()`:

```
fileInputStream.close();
```

When `fileCopy()` returns, the `fileInputStream` and `fileOutputStream` parameters are closed. But even if `fileInputStream` would not be closed, it would not point to the beginning of the file anymore (because `fileCopy()` uses it to read bytes from the file). Easiest in your case is to just create a new `FileInputStream` when you want to call `fileCopy()` again.

Comment: Can you elaborate this?
"even if fileInputStream would not be closed, it would not point to the beginning of the file anymore (because fileCopy() uses it to read bytes from the file)"

Comment: Even if you remove the `fileInputStream.close();` from the `fileCopy()` method which would result in `fileInputStream` not getting closed, you still couldn't pass it to another `fileCopy()` call because the first `fileCopy()` call reads it to the end of file, and attempting to read from it again would return nothing just that end of file is reached (because it is not "rewind").

Comment: You said that filecopy() method explicitly closes the fileinputstream
that means java uses call-by-reference approach??
if not how it is occuring? @icza

Comment: @SagarPudi In Java there are no pointers. Everything in Java is pass by value. A variable of type `FileInputStream` is a reference, and the reference is passed-by as a value, so it will refer to the same object.